# Force the start of content from top when one `td` higher than another?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two `<td>`'s while one have more content than another (both don't have a fixed height) and for this reason it looks bad as the `<td>` that has less content is not starting from the top but vertically centered.

Any way to fix that?

Comment: check `valign` in `<tr>`

Comment: `valign` in <td> itself fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

valign="top" would solve it:

```
<td valign="top"></td>
```